# C# как сделать чтобы в XML файле созданном с помощью LINQ to XML не выводилось xmlns=“”

Tags: c#, xml, linq2xml

Помогите пожалуйста, никак не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы в создаваемом файле никогда не выводилась пустая xmlns=""

есть код, создаём XML файл:

```
public void CreateKMLFile()
{
    XNamespace aw = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
        XElement kml = new XElement(aw + "kml");
            XElement document = new XElement("Document");

                XElement name = new XElement("name", "Моя карта");

            document.Add(name);
        kml.Add(document);
    xdoc.Add(kml);
    
    xdoc.Save("Object_In_map.kml");

    MessageBox.Show("Записал");
}
```

Создаётся файл:

А надо без вечно вылезающей xmlns="":

[image: на картинке]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238007/12888024

Comment: Спасибо,
но там удаляют все пространства имён уже из готового документа,
а как сделать так, чтобы они (xmlns="") там изначально не появлялись?

Comment: Что вам мешает использовать ту же методику, чтобы удалить ns у нужной вам ноды?

Comment: хотелось бы без лишних телодвижений)

Comment: Ждёте, чтобы вам готовый код кто-то написал. Ну ждите, может кто-то и напишет, когда-нибудь.

Comment: нет, 
просто я никогда не работал с XML документами, вот и не могу понять в чём проблема,
почему он упёрто вставляет xmlns="", 
м.б. решение секундное?

Comment: Секундное решение вам уже предложили. Могу предложить ещё правильное: если вы никогда не работали с XML -- пойти почитать теорию, почитать статьи о том, что такое неймспейсы, для чего они нужны. Долго, муторно, но зато вы сможете решать не только этот вопрос, но и множество других. Самостоятельно. А главное -- вы сможете понимать, вам дали правильное секундное решение или это секундный костыль, который вы посчитаете правильным способом работать с XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявление пространства имён распространяются на все вложенные элементы.

Вы создали узел `kml` с неймспейсом: `aw + "kml`. В xml получили `<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">`.

Но узел `Document` вы создаёте без пространства имён. Значит, он не относится к этому неймспейсу, значит, он относится к пустому пространству имён. Поэтому к нему автоматически добавляется `xmlns=""`.

Если в файле xml будет написано:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
```

то это будет означать, что оба узла без префикса: `kml` и `Document` относятся к одному и тому же пространству имён.
Если вам нужно именно это, то решение будет следующим:

```
XElement kml = new XElement(aw + "kml");
XElement document = new XElement(aw + "Document");
XElement name = new XElement(aw + "name", "Моя карта");
```

Ко всем элементам добавляем неймспейс `aw`.

---

Есть более краткая форма записи создания xml:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(aw + "kml",
        new XElement(aw + "Document",
            new XElement(aw + "name", "Моя карта")
)));
```

Именно её рекомендуется использовать.

---

Рекомендую [Namespace Tutorial](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-Namespace.html#intro) (нажимайте там ссылку Next) на zvon.org. Там хорошо, в цветах, показано, какие узлы к каким пространствам имён относятся.
Ещё бы форматирование там подправить...
Ага, есть там [вариант](http://zvon.org/xxl/NamespaceTutorial/Output/example1.html) с нормальным форматированием.

Comment: Огромное !СПАСИБО! за разъяснение!!!